# Batch script to find the names of modified files

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have some 500 .txt files in a folder. Of them, some 100 files contain a text  that I wish to change. I have used the below code to do that.

```
used Repl.bat and the below code:
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
type "%%F"|repl Apples Mangoes >"%%F.new"
move /y "%%F.new" "%%F"
)
```

Since this searches through all the files, the files are getting modified. I am unable to know in which files, the text has been replaced.

My actual task is to change the string and get the modified files into another folder. 
I tried using the below code to move the modified files. but since all the files are getting modified, I am clueless as what to do.

```
ECHO OFF
set source=C:\abc\
set destination=C:xyz\

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd1=%%j"."%%i"."%%k

if exist %destination% goto GO
:GO
mkdir %destination%%yyyymmdd1%
xcopy %source%* %destination% /m/s/d/y/c/v/r
echo. 
echo Finished copying %source% to %destination%
echo.
echo Created %destination%%yyyymmdd1%
pause
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see two approaches: 1) first check if a file contains the word to be replaced with the find command. Then either move the file unchanged or run it through repl. 2) call repl for all files, then compare original and copy using fc command

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am new to batch scripting and the above code is not my own. I have taken it from this site only. please elaborate it

Comment: SO is no 'write my code' site. The idea is to help you with suggestions. You need to be able to follow the advice given

Comment: Hi I tried using fc command and found the files modified. but is there anyway I can get the list of those modified files

Comment: `findstr /m "Apples" *.txt` will list the names of all files, that contain "Apples". Of course this makes only sense, BEFORE replacing apples with mangoes.

Comment: Next time before making the replace in files use `attrib.exe -a *.txt` which removes from all TXT files the archive attribute. The modification of the files results in setting archive attribute again on only the modified files. Then you could very easy copy the files with archive attribute set using command __xcopy__ with `/A` or `/M`. The archive attribute is designed for tasks like this one. Or modifies `repl.bat` even files not containing the searched string?

Answer (score 0):

To simply find out what files actually have been modifed, **with respect to their contents only**, you can use the following code snippet, which collects all the modified files in the log file `change.log`:

```
@echo off
> "change.log" (
    for %%F in ("*.txt") do (
        type "%%~F" | > "%%F.new" repl Apples Mangoes
        > nul fc /L "%%~F" "%%~F.new" || echo "%%~F"
        > nul move /Y "%%~F.new" "%%~F"
    )
)
```

This uses the `fc` command and the fact that it sets the `ErrorLevel` to `0` for matching files, and to `1` otherwise. `||` constitutes a conditional command separator which executes the next command only in case of a non-zero `ErrorLevel` (also known as exit code or return code).

The comparison is done in text mode. To change it to binary mode, replace `fc /L` by `fc /B`.

The redirection `> nul` avoids any messages of `fc` (like `Comparing files [...]`, `FC: no differences encountered`) or `move` (like `1 file(s) moved.`). If you want to see sch messages on screen, replace the `> nul` by `> con`.

To move the collected modified files afterwards, use the following command line in a batch script:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("change.log") do (move "%%~I" "\path\to\destination\")
```